# Including information from overlapping intervals into data.frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

```
dfA
"   ID  from    to  Lith
1   BG1 0       0.5 SED
2   BG1 0.5     0.6 GDI
3   BG1 0.6     2.8 GRN
3   ZH4 0       0.7 GRN
4   ZH4 0.7     3.0 GDI

dfB
"   ID  from    to  Weath
1   BG1 0       0.8 HW
2   BG1 0.8     1.5 SW
3   BG1 1.5     2.6 HW
4   ZH4 0       0.3 HW
5   ZH4 0.3     2.6 SW
```

I want the information from 'Lith' in dfA as a percentage of overlap (from 'to') in dfB. The result should look like this:

```
dfC
"   ID  from    to  Weath   GRN     GDI     SED
1   BG1 0       0.8 HW      0.25    0.125   0.625
2   BG1 0.8     1.5 SW      1       0       0
3   BG1 1.5     2.6 HW      1       0       0
4   ZH4 0       0.3 HW      1       0       0
5   ZH4 0.3     2.6 SW      0.1739  0.8261  0
```

Note that intervals of dfA do not coincide with those of dfB and that overlaps shall only be checked for same ID. Note also that up to three overlaps in one interval of dfB are possible. Intervals of dfA are always bigger than dfB.

My attempts so far have resulted in dead ends. Splitting the df by ID is not an option since the original amount of data is immense.

Comment: GRN: 0.2/0.8=0.25, GDI: 0.1/0.8=0.125, SED: 0.5/0.8=0.625 -> percentage of overlapping intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible `foverlaps` solution

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(dfA), ID, from, to)
setkey(setDT(dfB), ID, from, to)
res <- foverlaps(dfA, dfB)[, overlap := (pmin(to, i.to) - pmax(from, i.from))/(to - from)]
dcast(res, ID + from + to + Weath ~ Lith, value.var = "overlap", fill = 0)
#     ID from  to Weath      GDI      GRN   SED
# 1: BG1  0.0 0.8    HW 0.125000 0.250000 0.625
# 2: BG1  0.8 1.5    SW 0.000000 1.000000 0.000
# 3: BG1  1.5 2.6    HW 0.000000 1.000000 0.000
# 4: ZH4  0.0 0.3    HW 0.000000 1.000000 0.000
# 5: ZH4  0.3 2.6    SW 0.826087 0.173913 0.000
```

---

- `key` by `ID` and the intervals (nessacery in order for `foverlpas` to know on which column to operate)
- Run the `foverlaps` function in order to identify overlaps
- Define the `overlap` variable according to your rules
- Finally, `dcast` the result according to the columns of interest

Comment: The _dcast_ calls for an aggregation function. Normally there should be no duplicates but the dataset is yet not processed. Probably i will try your approach on the processed data since it seems simpler than Josilber 's approach (which on the other hand works on the raw data).

Comment: What do you want to do when there are duplicates?

Comment: From the context it is valid to just sum the values up.

Comment: So you have a `fun.aggregate` parameter within `dcast`. You can either specify `sum` or `mean` or whatever. You may need to use `dcast.data.table` instead of just `dcast` if you using older `data.table` versions

Comment: Seems to work, the rows displayed on the console look like what i want. But when viewing res it is still in long-format.

Comment: You need to save the result of the `dcast` operation using `res <- dcast(...` etc. Just look you save any operation in R...

Answer (score 1):

I would process each value of Lith (GRN, GDI, SED) one at a time, adding the generated column to `dfC`. For each value of Lith, I would first find the row of `dfA` corresponding to each row of `dfB` using the `match` function (this is the vector of row indices `r` in the `get.col` function below). Then I would calculate the normalized overlap in a vectorized manner using `pmax` and `pmin` (which is important since you say you have a large dataset).

```
get.col <- function(lith) {
  r <- match(paste(dfB$ID, lith), paste(dfA$ID, dfA$Lith))
  out <- pmax(0, pmin(dfA$to[r], dfB$to) - pmax(dfA$from[r], dfB$from)) /  # Overlap
    (dfB$to - dfB$from)  # Size of interval in dfB
  out[is.na(out)] <- 0  # Unmatched rows have no overlap
  out
}

dfC <- dfB
for (lith in unique(dfA$Lith)) {
  dfC[,lith] <- get.col(lith)
}
dfC
#    ID from  to Weath   SED      GDI      GRN
# 1 BG1  0.0 0.8    HW 0.625 0.125000 0.250000
# 2 BG1  0.8 1.5    SW 0.000 0.000000 1.000000
# 3 BG1  1.5 2.6    HW 0.000 0.000000 1.000000
# 4 ZH4  0.0 0.3    HW 0.000 0.000000 1.000000
# 5 ZH4  0.3 2.6    SW 0.000 0.826087 0.173913
```

Answer (score 1):

Merge the tables, perform your overlap function, reshape as desired.

```
library(reshape2)
m<-merge(dfB,dfA,by="ID",suffixes=c("",".y"))
overlap<-function(L1,R1,L2,R2) pmax(0,pmin(R1,R2)-pmax(L1,L2))
m$value<-overlap(m$from,m$to,m$from.y,m$to.y)/(m$to-m$from)
dcast(m,ID+from+to+Weath~Lith)

#>    ID from  to Weath      GDI      GRN   SED
#> 1 BG1  0.0 0.8    HW 0.125000 0.250000 0.625
#> 2 BG1  0.8 1.5    SW 0.000000 1.000000 0.000
#> 3 BG1  1.5 2.6    HW 0.000000 1.000000 0.000
#> 4 ZH4  0.0 0.3    HW 0.000000 1.000000    NA
#> 5 ZH4  0.3 2.6    SW 0.826087 0.173913    NA
```

Comment: Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x),  : 
  Join results in 1619843 rows; more than 112074 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)). Check for duplicate key values in i, each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that j runs for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.

Comment: I am not using `data.table`s here. Did you intend this comment for http://stackoverflow.com/a/32382938/1756702?

Comment: merge in reshape2 produced an error (Error in .Call(Ccopy, x) : NULL value passed as symbol address), so i tried data.table. Probably the data set is just too big.